# Array.push works strange when called in promise.then or promise.catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, promise

I wrote a method that should return a list of devices connected to the network that the client has.

```
export const connectedDevicesCore = (vpnId: string, vpnAuthToken: string) =>
    Service.listVPNConnectionsCore(vpnId, vpnAuthToken).then(vpnConnectedDevices => {
        let listPromises: Promise<any>[] = [];
        let listDevices: IDeviceData[] = [];
        vpnConnectedDevices.data.forEach((member: IZeroTierMember) => {
            listPromises.push(apiUtils.ApiGet(`http://${member.config.ipAssignments[0]}:5000/api/Main`).then((response: any) => {
                let device: IDeviceData = response.data;
                device.IPVpn = member.config.ipAssignments[0];
                listDevices.push(device);
            }).catch(() => {
                let device: IDeviceData = IDeviceExample;
                device.IPVpn = member.config.ipAssignments[0];
                device.DeviceName = member.name;
                device.Status = 'Have no client';
                listDevices.push(device);
            }));
        });
        return Promise.allSettled(listPromises).then(() => listDevices);
    });
```

ApiGet method:

```
export const ApiGet = (apiString: string, authToken: string | null = null) => {
    let config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` } };
    let promise = axios.get(apiString, authToken != null ? config : undefined);
    return promise
};
```

The idea was that if the client responded to the request, then the data that he transferred should be added to the array with all devices, if the requested client does not respond (i.e., is absent) Add a device with the same IP and information that he is without a client.

The problem is that writing data to the array is very strange, not the way it always is.

Example 1: There are 3 devices on the network, each without a client.

1. When the first request returns the "ETIMEDOUT" error, listDevices looks like this:

```
[ { DeviceName: 'HP Server',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.227',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] } ]
```

2. When the second request returns the "ETIMEDOUT" error, listDevices looks like this:

```
[ { DeviceName: 'Huawei P Smart 2021',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.64',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] },
  { DeviceName: 'Huawei P Smart 2021',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.64',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] } ]
```

3. When the third request returns the "ETIMEDOUT" error, listDevices looks like this:

```
[ { DeviceName: 'Test Client',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.147',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] },
  { DeviceName: 'Test Client',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.147',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] },
  { DeviceName: 'Test Client',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.147',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] } ]
```

Example 2: There are 3 devices on the network, only the first device has a client.

1. The first request writes the data returned by the client to listDevices.
2. The second request behaves as in example 1, only it does not overwrite the response of the first client.
3. The third request behaves as in example 1, only it does not overwrite the response of the first client.

That is, for example 2, the final answer will look like this:

```
[ { DeviceName: 'Test Client',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '192.168.8.3',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.147',
    MAC_Adress: 'C0B883046C3F',
    Status: 'Succes',
    AudioOutputs: [...{sth: "sth"}...] },
  { DeviceName: 'Huawei P Smart 2021',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.64',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] },
  { DeviceName: 'Huawei P Smart 2021',
    ID: 0,
    IP: '',
    IPVpn: '192.168.193.64',
    MAC_Adress: '',
    Status: 'Have no client',
    AudioOutputs: [] } ]
```

I tried many variations of this code, keeping the logical idea, but alas, it did not help in any way.

This code runs on Node.js 10.23.0 + Typescript 4.2.3

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"The second request behaves as in example 1, only it does not overwrite the response of the first client."* Can you explain that more? I don't see any code that would make it overwrite the response of the first client, so it makes sense that it doesn't do that. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem is that this code is not present, but it happens.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I found in the code. I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that in the failure case, you're not making a copy of `IDeviceExample` (which is oddly-named — I'd expect that to be an interface, but you're using it like an object). In your `catch` handler, change:

```typescript
let device: IDeviceData = IDeviceExample;
```

to

```typescript
let device: IDeviceData = {...IDeviceExample};
```

so that you're creating a new object, and assigning to `device.IPVpn` on that object won't affect other places you're using it. (Or if a deep copy is needed, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript). The code in the question doesn't need a deep copy, but I don't know what you do with these device objects in other code.)

---

Side note: Rather than pushing to a list as the promises settle and using `allSettled`, I suggest handling rejection inline (as you are) and using `Promise.all` without the extra array (`Promise.all` won't see any rejections, since you're handling them inline). Also, if `response.data` is `IDeviceData`, I suggest using `{data: IDeviceData}` as the type for `response` rather than `any` (in general, avoid `any`). In fact, you don't need to specify the type explicitly if `apiUtils.ApiGet` has a generic type parameter. Here's an example of that (also including changing the name `IDeviceExample` to `DeviceExample` per your comment below):

```typescript
export const connectedDevicesCore = (vpnId: string, vpnAuthToken: string) =>
    Service.listVPNConnectionsCore(vpnId, vpnAuthToken).then(vpnConnectedDevices => {
        const listPromises = Promise.all(vpnConnectedDevices.data.map(member => {
        //        ^ TypeScript can infer the type of this rather than your having to specify it explicitly (and no need for `any`)
            return apiUtils.ApiGet<IDeviceData>(`http://${member.config.ipAssignments[0]}:5000/api/Main`)
        //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−− *** type argument saying what the response will be
                .then(({data: device}) => { // *** No need for `any`, and you can use destructuring to put `data` in `device`
                    device.IPVpn = member.config.ipAssignments[0];
                    return device;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    let device: IDeviceData = {...DeviceExample}; // *** Copy the example object
                    device.IPVpn = member.config.ipAssignments[0];
                    device.DeviceName = member.name;
                    device.Status = "Have no client";
                    return device; // *** Converts rejection to fulfillment with this value
                });
        }));
        return listPromises;
    });
```

Just FWIW. :-) [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=1#code/PTAEF5NBlAXBDAdgEwLQEtEGdQDMD2ATqAJ74CuxsJADgKZYBQmsdhu8AxnaAJIAidAG7pu-eAlABvRqDl8ACgDUaiAFygssQpgDmAblnzBI7gDl4AWzoatOxAaNy4E8llva9hgL7NErdi4eXgAtNnwAFXQ2AFk6SwAjNmknUE58RFx0XQ0ZeXzQdBoAQSwsbMRrf3dNTwcAbQBdQ3zvFvlEKxta+0dfFjYObj4lBTMAYQzEOk5WZBNRBml8kD40wjoJOmRQWAALdBwMngJiAAMhVUnEadnthe4sM9AkgBt8AHdU5Al4DVDwlFYvEkoQmj4-AEhsEAOJ0WAAJQYNAyWB4UgKmNAq14602c12ByO0zwRFAZ3gNHQAFVYOhXlgAHTFKlw2Bnb6-f4POjiBAQxjIGaveAbUCveGgHkAUQAHlYaBLucJFnz4IYhZwRWKJbAYGxTN08vJXodYKMJlMZnTUZMNgAKS6IXjIDy9AA0oCdxXI+wi+AA1nR1D09ABKDQKQj4SyHOgAHl4FuutzmPKwAD4IZrtTxdaBKTS6Qzciz0GyNPG1RFaHQM-bKK83eGIBnQFGY3H41IfggNNXa94M21GIxVpBwKBpShakg0JgcHPNOROHtR3RZSjCHr0tgd1a7vMVY87TxJ47VC7mw5Pd7fXt-UGQ3YW+AM6loAbFozTVpkwebWwU8L2dZBb1UH0-UDYMw0ZfZgxAlNrXuY8ljfFIsTSVE9V-WAO1jNEcEnfC40ZeBXleRCAJQw0mV7eBGUsSl7WsRJknQ41MVWLEAD1QBrehoE4HQaB3JBCkyZJ4N2WtQHwXBCUOUBCAkPYpL2cSyEoUANJEBxdnwTR6E4dBcBIQo9Q3RVRHQWBXnM+0l0QQzpm2UlziQEgzjDVJMI2WBKEQAsqVpekmTLNlEx5NV6zOPZYFgGg1BAAASKRWNBRldyyXRGSKUpyl0Spg1gLB6gABkabw1AAVnK+rgELYAYngTBvN8+RuMw7qCh4vr+oG-rACQiEahtAAAqSaZPoAtCF0cgqj1LB4BIPRQA+DS9WkjYsBRbAeA+elXheOgOp6uC1MQe17R7LlQCFQ1vDDVtllWSbxtAMwXLoNzTnJTyzk9JctLScS3B4IU7BXALegM0AaF9cl6OeTAkdQjkep6h7v14ZRVAgUAMrYLKMhyvKSjKCpFrKyr2kxrF-MC+7ULp+nQCes7uqyiRV2u56OM5+n82x7hlUNNUCakRlpZleVLEVOg2mxMB3tASYaHM6SNwVCU5ISAAra1BcxkW6EZXGVCCycicIEnMmycmCqpkqaeaY2sdQxkeQsawCZtxlOmsVm2fkU3GRcAKiNAAAiAAJeAhB4Zy0lNEro+DkPlPhJnTf0ZWJqm65E+3HANkN2Z0AyOHcHIV4sgoxb1tsvZFJwIRyPIU7M-ZsMM7kJ7e85xnCCC3CSMI1mnsMIA)

Comment: Thanks, change to 
```let device: IDeviceData = {... IDeviceExample}; ```
worked! 
Btw, IDeviceExample is just an object that repeats all the fields in the interface. 
Made it so that it would be possible to create classes. I will rename this IDeviceExample to DeviceExample.

Comment: @Crossmax - Glad that helped! FWIW, I updated my example at the end to get rid of the `any` types and such. Happy coding!